# WPF/EF Code First mdf file created is not accessible with tools

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I create an MDF file using the CustomConnectionFactory and PromptForDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChages "way" from the "Code First" O'Reily's book, the file is created but it's not accessible from VS or SSMS. I am able to see the DB tables and parameters created by expending the treeview in VS Server Explorer, but on "Show Data" it shows an error: "**The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)**". I looked this error up and seems there's problem with server permissions, however setting the SSMS with the highest permissions (sysadmin, owner, etc) didn't help. I am thinking there's maybe permissions issue with the file itself. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's the code:

App.xaml.cs:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
            {
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ""));
                Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new CustomConnectionFactory();
                Database.SetInitializer(new PromptForDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChages<AppEntities>());

                using (var context = new AppEntities())
                {
                    context.Clicks.Add(new MouseClick
                        {
                            DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now,
                            DateTimeModified = DateTime.Now,
                            Id = 1,
                            IsActive = true,
                        });
                }


                var mainView = new MainView
                    {
                        DataContext = new ViewModelMain(new AppEntities())
                    };

                mainView.Show();
            }
```

CustomConnectionFactory.cs:

```
    class CustomConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
        {
            public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
            {
                var name = nameOrConnectionString.Split('.').Last().Replace("Entities", string.Empty);

                var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = @".\SQLEXPRESS",
                    AttachDBFilename = @"|DataDirectory|\App.mdf",
                    InitialCatalog = name,
                    IntegratedSecurity = true,
                    MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
                    UserInstance = true
                };
                return new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
            }
        }
```

PromptForDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges.cs:

```
public class PromptForDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChages<TContext> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
    {
        public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
        {
            var exists = context.Database.Exists();

            if (exists && context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (exists && context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
            {
                context.Database.Delete();
            }

            context.Database.Create();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After recreating the same on a home computer everything works fine. Seems like there's some network restrictions at work.